# Images.xcassets size is changing when converted to .car?

Tags: ios

The original Folder Size of Images.xcassets is 138MB in my app.

I made archive, and export it as **.ipa** file. I have changed extention, ipa to zip. I have extracted it.

I saw the size of **250MB+**.

When I upload it to iTune, it compresses, but still size of Application is huge.

I have read steps by apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014195-CH1-MEASURE

It is not worthy. I want to know reason, why **.car** file is huge than original images size?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does Byte Swapping to enhance performance. This Byte Swapping needs to add padding bytes. This makes your file size huge.

However when it will be deployed to Apple Store, then will slice your binaries and size will be reduced for end users.

Comment: Can I see reference where Apple mentioned this?

Comment: I do not have the link bookmarked. Please find other reference over here http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html